# fs.writefile is not a function / Typescript / JSON

Tags: node.js, json, typescript, writefile

Whenever I try to write data into a .json file I get an error. It says that **'fs.writefile'** is not a function.

**My function:**

```
const fs = require('fs');


function write(data: Map<string, number>) {
    fs.writefile("users.json", JSON.stringify(data), function(err: any) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('complete');
        }
    );
}
```

**The error:**
(node:4408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: fs.writefile is not a function

Could someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript property names are case sensitive. The `writeFile` method has a capital `F`, but you have `writefile` with a lowercase `f`.

See: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback